# Shuffling "Alt"/"windows"/"Alt Gr" on just USB keyboard (and possibly not laptop keyboard)

Tags: keyboard, xorg, kde, xkb, xinput

Due to unfortunate misunderstanding in the label reading, I have ordered and received a [Das Keyboard 4](https://www.alternate.es/DasKeyboard/DASK4MACSFT-USEU-Teclado-para-gaming/html/product/1341658?event=search)... *for Mac*. Which would have been nice if I didn't use a KDE Neon desktop (which is a KDE-specific brand of Ubuntu Bionic).

All in all it doesn't change much because the layout is *almost* identical to the standard US layout my ThinkPad has. However, there is one tiny difference: they switched the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and Super keys. To be precise, here are the keyboards next one to each other.

[image: Both keyboards side to side with key mapping]

The red arrow shows what happens when I click something on the Das Keyboard. There is several issues but my main beef is that there is a <kbd>cmd</kbd> key on the right of the space bar and I really need that key to be my <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> because I use it *a lot* for international characters.

After trying the keyboard with `xev`, I received the following events:

```
#############################
#### alt option (left) ####
#############################

KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0xc400001,
    root 0x1a0, subw 0x0, time 360620584, (875,245), root:(2795,282),
    state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
   
   
##################
### cmd (left) ###
##################

KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0xc400001,
    root 0x1a0, subw 0x0, time 360669131, (1346,776), root:(3266,813),
    state 0x10, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

    
###################
### cmd (right) ###
###################

KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0xc400001,
    root 0x1a0, subw 0x0, time 360701716, (635,185), root:(2555,222),
    state 0x10, keycode 134 (keysym 0xffec, Super_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

    
##########################
### alt option (right) ###
##########################

KeyPress event, serial 42, synthetic NO, window 0xc400001,
    root 0x1a0, subw 0x0, time 360746058, (705,144), root:(2625,181),
    state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

So far I've been looking into:

- Creating a new keymap, but it seems complicated because the modifier keys are not really part of the keymap itself
- I've ran `setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_alt_win` which seems to have changed the keys in `xev` but now there is no key acting as <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> at all

As a bonus, if someone could help me find a solution that separates the layout of the laptop's keyboard from the USB keyboard, that would be fantastic. Here is what `xinput` tells me:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech MX Vertical                      id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Metadot - Das Keyboard Das Keyboard       id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Metadot - Das Keyboard Das Keyboard       id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech MX Vertical                      id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Any help on getting this tweaked is super welcome!

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but have you considered to just pull the keys off and swap them?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, doing so will just change the label without changing the key code sent to the computer so it would most likely be ineffective. However I do intend on doing that when I've figured how to invert the key codes :)

Comment: Ah, my bad. I thought you meant that the alt sent out cmd and visa versa. My bad.